Remove NavigationView gap in Content area (WinUI 3 version)
Anyone know how to reduce or remove this padding on the content area of NavigationView (WinUI 3)?? I'd like to do this without using a Style. Is there a resource I can override?
The reason I ask is because if you remove the Back button, the area is not correctly aligned when in narrow view.


Based on the solution provided by @Andrew-KeepCoding, the only change needed to achieve this was the name of the Key:
<NavigationView Header="Sample Page" ...>
    <NavigationView.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewMinimalHeaderMargin">24,0,0,0</Thickness>
    </NavigationView.Resources>
</NavigationView>


You can override the NavigationViewHeaderMargin, which is 56,44,0,0 (Left,Top,Right,Bottom) by default.
<NavigationView Header="Sample Page" ...>
    <NavigationView.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewHeaderMargin">56,0,0,0</Thickness>
    </NavigationView.Resources>
</NavigationView>

You can learn about this in the generic.xaml file.

Unfortunately that didn't work, did exactly that, specified the Thickness in my NavigationView.Resources, but the gap yet remains.
